# Java - Statements / Conversions | Pulpcore

Tags: java, actionscript-3, pulpcore

[please note this may require AS3 + Java knowledge]

Background Information:

I'm trying to build a game using Java + Pulpcore, but I'm fairly new to the scene.  The game I'm building could possibly be more performance intensive than I thought, and I know Java would solve my problems with this, but there are a couple questions I have dealing with strict-types, etc.

Here is my code in AS3:

Main.as3

```
import org.tbmb.champions.Container;
import org.tbmb.zombies.ZContainer;

public class Main extends MovieClip {

    // ******* temporary properties ******* /
    private var blunder:Container = null;
    // *******                      ******* /

    public function Main() {

        init(); // initialize objects

    }

    public function init():void {

        blunder = new Container(Blunder as Class);

    } // end of class

}
```

Container.as3

```
 package org.tbmb.champions {

     import flash.display.MovieClip;

     public class Container extends MovieClip {

          public function Container(champ:*) {

          } // end of constructor

     } // end of class

 } // end of package
```

Blunder.as3

```
package org.tbmb.champions.blunder {

    import flash.display.MovieClip;

    public class Blunder extends MovieClip {

        public function Blunder() {

        } // end of constructor

    } // end of class

} // end of constructor
```

1.)  How would I rewrite in Java?

```
blunder = new Container(Blunder as Class);
```

2.) How would I be able to accept any Classes in Java for the above line within my Container class?

```
public function Container(champ:*) {
```

I need to do this because I'm sending different champion classes (depending on what the user picks) to a containing class that will hold all their other classes (health, etc).  I need my Container class to accept any Class rather than just one; what type would I use?

Here is what I have in Java so far:

ZomboPulp.java (Main Class)

```
import pulpcore.scene.Scene2D;

import org.tnpfk.champions.Container;
import org.tnpfk.champions.blunder.Blunder;

import pulpcore.sprite.FilledSprite;
import pulpcore.image.Colors;

public class ZomboPulp extends Scene2D {

    FilledSprite background = new FilledSprite(Colors.WHITE);

    Container container = null; // Container that contain's blunder, 
    // and all his objects (health, mana, etc)

    public void load() {

        this.initScreen(); // initialize main screen.
        this.initObjects(); // initialize our objects.

    } // end of load();

    public void initScreen() {

        add(background);

    } // end of initScreen();

    public void initObjects() {

        container = new Container(Blunder as Class); // ERROR HERE

    } // end of initObjects();

}
```

Container.java

```
package org.tnpfk.champions;

public class Container {

    public Container(Object champ) {

    } // end of constructor

} // end of class
```

Sorry for the lengthy post, and thanks for any help.  By the way, I did check StackOverflow; and Google, but I was unable to find anything about this.

Thanks,
jvmpulp

Answer (score 1):

Alrighty! I have no experience with PulpCore, but I do know both AS3 and Java, so I think I can answer your question. First off, I guess I don't 100% understand what you need to do with the champ object in the Container class, and I really don't understand why you were doing `Blunder as Class` instead of just passing an instance of Blunder. Either way, here's what I'd recommend with what you have as of now:

```
public void initObjects() {

    container = new Container(Blunder.class);

}
```

As you can see, you can get a Class instance just by getting the `class` property of any class. Now, you have the right idea with using `Object` as the type for the Container constructor for any type. However, using `Object` is bad practice (use method overloading/more specific types instead), and it's not even required here. Getting the `class` property will always be of type `Class`, even though they represent different classes. So, rewrite the constructor as this:

```
public Container(Class champ) {

}
```

Then, do whatever you need to do with the class.

Now, that's basically a direct port, but it seems some of the things you're doing are bad practice. The whole system of passing a `Class` object seems irrelevant and unnecessary; why not just pass an instance of the object? For example, like so:

```
public class Container {

    protected Champion champ;

    public Container(Champion champ) {

        this.champ = champ;

    }

}
```

Now, make `Champion` an abstract class that contains the common methods for all the champions:

```
public abstract class Champion {

    protected Something something;

    abstract Something getSomething();

}
```

(Obviously, the variable/method shown here are just examples.) Then, have your individual Champion classes subclass `Champion`:

```
public class Blunder extends Champion {

    public Something getSomething() {
        return this.something;
    }

}
```

Etc. Then, finally, do this:

```
public void initObjects() {

    container = new Container(new Blunder());

}
```

Obviously, this is a basic example, and you don't have to take my advice. But it would probably be easier to do than the system you already had in AS3.